SemanticKITTI rotation troubles
The pose data provided with the SemanticKITTI (https://semantic-kitti.org/) LIDAR dataset is formatted unusually. For instance, they use a 'yzx' coordinate system instead of the standard 'xyz'. My problem is that there seems to be an issue with the rotation matrix. When the streets curve left or right, they flip on their side before correcting when going straight. The corners also exhibit an odd shape due to the rotation matrix. I've been struggling to fix these issues for days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a turning point of the street
I have tried organising the rotation matrices in different orders but with no success. I am not an expert in matrices equations so I was hoping somebody with more experience would know.
